# How to insert emoji into NSTextView without shifting the line down?

Tags: cocoa, emoji, nstextview

How do I insert emoji into an `NSTextView` without moving the line down?

If I insert an emoji character into an `NSTextView`, the whole line will shift down a couple pixels. If I remove the emoji character, it will move back up to its original position.

On the other hand, if I insert an emoji into an `NSTextField`, the line doesn't move at all, even when the text in the line is the same font and size as it was in the `NSTextView`.

[image]

You can see this behavior in TextEdit. When you are typing in the main editor area (an `NSTextView`), emoji make the lines move down. When you are typing in the Find search bar (`NSTextField`) emoji don't affect the line position.

I've tried setting `typingAttributes` with various `NSParagraphStyle` settings (`lineHeight`, `lineSpacing`, `lineHeightMultiple`, `max/minLineHeight`) and also raising or lowering the baseline to no avail. In fact, some of these settings don't help the emoji behavior, but they do mess up the vertical alignment of the spelling error indicators.

Comment: If you use textField with more than one row - every emoji will shift your alignment. Because regular symbol have limits for calculation lower than bounds and emoji symbol have limits == bound. This sad story from iOS.

Comment: The line height can be forced in subclasses of either `NSLayoutManager`, where you can adjust the bounding rect, or `NSTypesetter` (The two `NSTypesetter.getLineFragmentRect` are promising). Try to override the height values of the `NSRectPointer`s with a fixed value and see if that does the trick,

Comment: Or have a look at "Neat" which swizzles line height computations: https://github.com/leavez/Neat