# Text position shifts down & font also changes when an emoji is added in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstextview

I am using a NSTextView in my application. Whenever I add an emoji, the text present gets shifted down. I tried using **setLineFragmentPadding** to text container of the NSTextView, alos tried setting **setTextContainerInset** & alos **lineBreakMode** to clipping. But,still the text shifts down when an emoji is added. How to avoid this text shifting & change in font?

[image: textview showing text moving down]

1st Image - With & Without emoji added to text.[Added 2nd & 3rd image here for better understanding]

2nd Image - only text.

3rd image - text with emoji.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to insert emoji into NSTextView without shifting the line down?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39460470/4244136).

Comment: @Willeke it has no answer.

Comment: Apparently this is how emoji work. The emoji font is a bit higher.

Comment: @Willeke Same doesn't happen with NSSearchField.

Comment: The text view is configured differently.

Comment: Try `textView.layoutManager.typesetterBehavior = NSTypesetterBehavior_10_2_WithCompatibility;`. Use at your own risk.

Comment: @Willeke typesetterBehavior  Didn't work.